# ORA-29283: invalid file operation when reading a file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have following privileges  CREATE ANY DIRECTORY, read, write on directory DOCS to user_name

I am using oracle 10g on Windows.

I have first created the directory as

`CREATE DIRECTORY DOCS AS 'C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\file';`

Directory created successfully.

Now when I tried to execute following code

```
DECLARE
 l_file         UTL_FILE.file_type;
 l_location     VARCHAR2(100) := 'DOCS';
 l_filename     VARCHAR2(100) := 'test.pdf';
 l_text         VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
-- Open file.
 l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_location, l_filename, 'r', 32767);
-- Read and output first line.
 UTL_FILE.get_line(l_file, l_text, 32767);
 dbms_output.put_line('First Line: |' || l_text || '|');
-- Close the file.
 UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
END;
```

I get these errors

> ORA-29283: invalid file operation
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 475
>
> ORA-29283: invalid file operation
>
> ORA-06512: at line 8

Comment: do you have access to the directory? check the utl_file_dir database parameter

Comment: You have a directory on your desktop named 'file'? Does the Oracle account have access to your home directory?

Comment: I have checked the directory exists by select * from dicrectories. @AlexPoole

Comment: I'm talking about the operating system directory and operating system account's ability to see it; not the Oracle Directory object. They have to tie up, but Oracle has to be able to access the operating system directory too.

Comment: And how to check this? @AlexPoole

Comment: How I can check I have access to directory. @davegreen100

Comment: the directory needs to be listed in UTL_FILE_DIR parameter, it will also work if the paramter is set to *

Comment: I entered the directory path as follow in SQL PLUS
C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\file'
I get this
 `UTL_FILE_DIR = 'C:`
@davegreen100

Comment: Kindly help me. I am beginner not an expert in oracle.
@AlexPoole

Comment: Kindly help me. I am beginner not an expert in oracle. @davegreen100

Comment: Oracle is its own user (or at least it is in Unix. I don't know precisely how it works in Windows), and you're trying to write into a folder owned by a different user. Create a folder called C:\files\ or something and point your DOCS directory to that.

Comment: Doesn't work @StevenEccles

Answer (score 0):

i don't have access to oracle on windows, but something like this in you init.ora file

```
UTL_FILE_DIR=c:\DOCS
```

you will then need to restart oracle

you should also be able to do the following (but i've not tested it)

```
alter system set utl_file_dir=c:\DOCS scope=both
```

Comment: running this
`alter system set utl_file_dir=c:\DOCS scope=both` 
give me a error 
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified @davegreen100

Comment: The OP is using directory objects, [which is preferred](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#i996762), so setting this init parameter shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: What should I do ? @AlexPoole

Comment: @MuhammadHannan, in that case you will need to set it in the init.ora file and restart. But if what AlexPoole saying is correct then this will not solve your problem

if you are using directory objects have you granted access to the oracle directories? GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY <dirname> TO DBA

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of things you should check if you encounter this error message because `UTL_FILE` isn't very precise about pointing out what aspect of file I/O is being violated in these scenarios!

- Make sure the physical directory exists on the OS on which the database is running.  An obvious point perhaps, but if you're in an environment with many databases running on many servers and those databases often get copied around, it's not always that easy to work out which database writes to which directory!  Details will also vary according to which OS you're running Oracle on, of course.
- Make sure the OS user running Oracle (i.e. the OS user running the Oracle service) has read/write privileges to that directory at OS level.  Again, this is an OS configuration, so depending on the setup, your DBA might not have access and require additional IT help!
- Make sure that your directory `DOCS` is pointing to the correct physical OS directory
- Make sure that the Oracle user executing your code has access to read/write into the Oracle directory `DOCS`.  This can be done by: `GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY DOCS TO user_or_role_name;`
- If reading a file, make sure that the file exists with all the necessary OS privileges granted (as discussed above)
- If writing a file, make sure that your filename doesn't include invalid characters.  For example, Windows doesn't accept `*` or `>` characters in file-names.  If your program generates the file-name dynamically from data (which is likely, unless you want every file to be named `test.txt`) and that data includes an invalid character, you could be chasing your tail for a while trying to find the problem!!  Make sure your file-name parameter has a some kind of `Safe_File_Name(filename_)` function wrapped around it!!